# Would have past participle

Tags: subjunctives

I have learnt a usage of "would have" past  participle is that, it is used to explain past  feeling that I wanted to do but could not. But this below sentence written in news paper is not matching with that definition "alone would have compelled another state to hit the pause button"

Comment: The full sentence containing your example text is [*Such a gross travesty of justice, where innocent men are hanged, alone would have compelled another state to hit the pause button; to investigate what went wrong; to correct course.*](https://www.dawn.com/news/1452747) Which I have to say is stylistically *appalling* (that parenthetical clause before ***alone*** is clumsy, to say the least). And the very next sentence starts with *Whichever side of the argument on capital punishment one may stand on,* which is pretty bad too. Not a particularly good source to learn English from, I suggest.

Comment: ...but the construction *X would have [done Y]* doesn't necessarily imply that X *wanted* to do Y (but for some reason was unable to do so). It just refers to X's preferred choice of action in some *hypothetical* context (in the past, or in some "timeless" alternate reality). The "alternate reality" in your cited context would be one where the "gross travesty of justice" had happened in some other state / country (not Pakistan) - in which case that *other* country would be compelled to react differently.